# Does this stand also for $f$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, ring-theory, roots

We consider the differential equation $Ly=f$ in the ring of exponential sums $\mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ so we have that $f=\sum_{i=0}^n C_i e^{\lambda_i x}$.

If we apply the superposition principle we have to solve differential equations of the form $Ly=e^{bx}$.

If $b$ is a root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous equation of multiplicity $M$, then the solution is of the form $Cx^Me^{b x}\notin \mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$.

If $b$ is not a root of the characteristic equation of the homogeneous equation, then the solution is of the form $Ce^{b x}\in \mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$.

Therefore, the differential equation has a solution in the ring if $b$ is not a root of the characteristic equation, right?

This is equivalent to $L(e^{b x}) \neq 0$, right?

Does this stand also for the original differential equation? So is it $$L\left (\sum_{i=0}^n C_i e^{\lambda_i x}\right ) \neq  0$$ ?

Comment: Is $L$ a constant coefficient differential operator?

Comment: Yes, it is also linear. @robjohn

Comment: Does this stand also when we have the sum? Or does it only stand when we have a single exponential? @robjohn

Answer (score 1):

If $L=P(D)$, where $P$ is a polynomial, then $L(e^{\lambda_ix})=P(\lambda_i)e^{\lambda_ix}$. Thus, if the $\lambda_i$ avoid the roots of $P$, then for
$$
f=\sum_ia_ie^{\lambda_ix}
$$
we have $Ly=f$ for
$$
y=\sum_i\frac{a_i}{P(\lambda_i)}e^{\lambda_ix}
$$

Comment: But if $\lambda_i$ doesn't avoid the roots, there is no $y \in \mathbb{C}[e^{\lambda x} \mid \lambda \in \mathbb{C}]$ that solves $Ly=f$, right?

Comment: That is correct.